# comparing data sets in R

Tags: r

I am trying to compare two sets of proteomic data. I want to be able to look at the differences and similarities between the two sets. I would also like to be able to draw a venn diagram showing the number of differences and similarities found. my knowledge of R is limited. I have not found another program that can do this. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I would say you have to specify your question (datasets) to get any sufficient answer.

But in general you can compare two objects like this:

```
data_1 = cbind(c(3,4,5),c(6,9,2)) 

data_2 = cbind(c(1,4,8),c(6,7,2))

data_1 == data_2
```

which will result in sth. like this:

```
      [,1]  [,2]
[1,] FALSE  TRUE
[2,]  TRUE FALSE
[3,] FALSE  TRUE
```